# Unable to access associative array values

Tags: php, arrays, echo, var-dump

I have two config files. The first, which is called `configs.php` contains an array with some values:

```
$welcomeConfigs = [
  "title" => "welcome",
  "description" => "a description"
];
```

The second file includes the `configs.php` one and use the its array to generate some other variables. The second file is called `views.php`.

```
$viewConfigs = VIEW . 'Configs';
$pathToViewConfigs = VIEW . '/configs.php';

include($pathToViewConfigs);

var_dump($$viewConfigs);
```

In `index.php`:

```
define("VIEW", "welcome");
include('views.php');
```

I need to store in the `$title` variable, for example, the value of the associative array, but when I try to do it nothing happens. I tried to use var_dump to check if the syntax was correct and I used en external fiddle to check if something was wrong, but nothing is actually wrong.

When type `var_dump($$viewConfigs);` the output is `{ ["title"]=> string(7) "welcome" ["description"]=> string(13) "a description" }`

but when I type `var_dump($$viewConfigs['title']);` the output is `NULL`.

How can I fix this? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use this syntax:

```
var_dump( ${$viewConfigs}['title'] );
```

that interpret `$viewConfigs` as variable name. The form `$$viewConfigs['title']` interpret as variable name the content od `$viewConfigs['title']`, that not exists.

I hope I have been clear.

(Edit:) See more about variable variables on [PHP Official site](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Thank you that is correct!! (I have to wait 6 minutes before checking it as the correct answer though)

Comment: Yes, and from the manual on "variable variables"  the pertinent section: "In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an ambiguity problem. That is, if you write $$a[1] then the parser needs to know if you meant to use $a[1] as a variable, or if you wanted $$a as the variable and then the [1] index from that variable. The syntax for resolving this ambiguity is: ${$a[1]} for the first case and ${$a}[1] for the second."

Comment: @gview Thank you. I have added the link in the answer.